# Get AST for C fragment, using Clang?

Tags: clang

I am building a clang plugin, and I am trying to generate the AST for a C fragment at some point within the plugin. Something like:

```
std::string c_code = "...";
getAST(c_code);
```

Can someone point me to, how to go about this?

Comment: You definitely don't want to just use `-dump-ast` from the command line `clang`?

Comment: I am trying to do this 'within' a clang plugin. I import a snippet of C code from another tool, and I would like to extract it's AST within the plugin so I can add it to the original C code.

Comment: @SaswatPahdi, I take it my answer didn't work?

Comment: Thanks Ishamael. Your answer was definitely helpful. I am still figuring out some parts.
FYI, I didn't down-vote your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be there are several ways to achieve this, but finally I got the following snippet working and to me it looks simple enough:

```
//arguments to the compiler
std::unique_ptr <std::vector<const char*>> args(new std::vector<const char*>());
args->push_back("my_file.c");

//do the magic
ASTUnit *au = ASTUnit::LoadFromCommandLine(
  &(*args)[0],
  &(*args)[0] + args->size(),
  IntrusiveRefCntPtr<DiagnosticsEngine>(
    CompilerInstance::createDiagnostics(new DiagnosticOptions)),
  StringRef()
);

//get the translation unit node
Declr *d = au->getASTContext().getTranslationUnitDecl();
```

Simpler alternatives or suggestions to improve this are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a code snipped ready to copy-paste, but the idea that I used before is the following:

Note that [clang_parseTranslationUnit](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__TRANSLATION__UNIT.html#ga2baf83f8c3299788234c8bce55e4472e) has `unsaved_files` as one of the arguments. So the idea would be to provide a command line `g++ main.cpp`, and then provide an unsaved file with name `main.cpp` and the content from your string.